# Update Listview from another class

Tags: c#

How can I update an item by changing the collection in another class?
For example:

```
class A {
    private Dictionary<int, B> elems;
    public A() {
        elems = new Dictionary<int, B>();
    }
    public addElem() {
        B b = new B();
        b.name = "123";
        b.id = 321;
        elems[0] = b;
    } 
}

class B {
    public string name;
    public int id;
}
```

How do I update, for example, listView in the Form1 class when I change the dictionary?

I tried to use events, but this method does not suit me.
Thank you!

Comment: What do you mean "this method does not suit me" ???

Comment: I think that there is a way to solve the problem better

Comment: There is Observer pattern http://www.dofactory.com/net/observer-design-pattern

Comment: You can couple class A and B (for start). Just pass "this" in method "addElem" to B constructor like this: B b = new B(this);  And in class B you can take it from constructor and save in to field. So later you can take that field and call it's members